# Comparison Test for series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to use the comparison test to determine whether the series:

$\sum\frac{3^n+7^n}{3^n+8^n}$

converges or diverges.

So far, I've tried splitting it into $\frac{3^n}{3^n + 8^n} + \frac{7^n}{3^n + 8^n} $ but have gotten nowhere

Comment: The first one is dominated by $\left(\frac 38\right)^n$.  The second is dominated by $\left(\frac 78\right)^n$.

Comment: I see now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For the numerator,
$$3^n+7^n\le 2.7^n$$

For the denominator,
$$3^n+8^n\ge 8^n$$

thus

$$0<\frac{3^n+7^n}{3^n+8^n}\le 2\frac{7^n}{8^n}$$

Answer (score 0):

It will be simpler to use  the *limit comparison test* via *asymptotice equivalence of functions:
$$3^n+7^n\sim_\infty 7^n,\quad3^n+8^n\sim_\infty 8^n,\quad\text{ hence }\quad \frac{3^n+7^n}{3^n+8^n}\sim_\infty \frac{7^n}{8^n}=\Bigl(\frac78\Bigr)^n,$$
which converges.